# How can I select rows with value of No or NULL when the parameter = 'No' and rows with value of 'Yes' when the parameter ='Yes'

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I need to select rows based upon the parameter '@HotList'.

When '@HotList' = 'Yes' I need to pull all rows where the 'co.ro_HotList' field holds the value of 'Yes' 
When '@HotList' = 'No' I need to pull all rows where the 'co.ro_HotList' field holds the value of 'No' OR null

I can select the rows where the value is 'Yes' or 'No' just based on the parameter, but cannot figure out how to also select the Null rows when parameter is 'No'. How can I modify the provided code to achieve this?

I have tried using a case statement in the where clause but with no luck.

```
SELECT ds.*                     
FROM Rotex_DailyShipmentNotShip ds
left outer join CRM_MSCRM..SalesOrder co ON ds.SOP#=co.Name 
WHERE co.ro_HotList = @HotList
```

Comment: are there any other option besides Y N Null?

Answer (score 1):

Try this in the where:

```
ISNULL(co.ro_HotList,'No') = @HotList
```

ISNULL will evaluate a null to the 2nd input so all nulls are treated as 'No' in your case.

Comment: Would this statement still pass the co.ro_HotList field if the values are 'Yes' or 'No'?

Comment: @JustinWade. Yes. ISNULL will evaluate the expression as the actual value unless it is null then the result is the 2nd input.

Comment: COALESCE is another way to do this. COALESCE evaluates to the first nonnull value.

Answer (score 0):

Keith answer is the correct one, but for completness you mention you try `CASE` and this is how should be done using `CASE`.

```
  WHERE CASE WHEN co.ro_HotList IS NULL 
             THEN 'No'
             ELSE co.ro_HotList
        END  = @HotList
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write the filtering condition as shown below:

```
SELECT ds.*                     
FROM Rotex_DailyShipmentNotShip ds
left outer join CRM_MSCRM..SalesOrder co ON ds.SOP#=co.Name 
WHERE @HotList = 'Yes' and co.ro_HotList = 'Yes'
   OR @HotList = 'No' and (co.ro_HotList = 'No' or co.ro_HotList is null)
```

Comment: You probably need parenthesis to separate OR conditions

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza `AND` has higher precedence than `OR`, so it should work as expected. However, I agree it could be clearer for the casual reader.

Answer (score 0):

Several answers to the OP question are valid because they return the expected results, but most of them are inefficient because they prevent proper index use.

Enclosing column names in expressions such as case expressions or functions prevent SQL Server from using indexes.

Predicates with OR operator and parameter conditions also prevent an efficient execution plan.

There are several ways to construct the query in an efficient way:

**Add a computed column**

Add a computed column such as:

ALTER TABLE ADD HotList AS ISNULL(ro_HotList, 'No')

And index it. The query then will be simpler and index friendly:

WHERE HotList = @HotList

**Smart Client Application**

The client application could be smart enough to do the following (pseudocode)

```
If HostListParameter is "No" then execute the query:
   SELECT <column list>
   FROM Whatever
   WHERE ro_HostList = 'No' OR ro_HostList IS NULL
Else execute this other query:
   SELECT <column list>
   FROM Whatever
   WHERE ro_HostList = @HotList
  Invalid parameter
```

**Use T-SQL Batch with logic**

Instead of executing a single select statement, execute a batch with logic

```
IF @HostList = 'No'
BEGIN
   SELECT <column list>
   FROM Whatever
   WHERE ro_HostList = 'No' OR ro_HostList IS NULL 
END
ELSE
BEGIN
   SELECT <column list>
   FROM Whatever
   WHERE ro_HostList = @HotList
END
```

**Use a stored procedure**

You can create a stored procedure that perform the same logic as the preceding T-SQL batch

**Use `OPTION(RECOMPILE)`**

Adding OPTION(RECOMPILE)

adding OPTION(RECOMPILE) to The Impaler answer leads to better execution plans that can use indexes, however it also prevent plan reuse.

**But low selectivity non covering indexes are rarely used**

If a column holds few values a non covering index is mostly useless.

In this case I think the column can only hold 'Yes', 'No' or NULL. So indexing it would not improve performance. And the best answer is the KeithL's one.